# forkJoin within forEach loop

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an array of objects.
Something like this -

```
const arrayOfObject = [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}];
```

I want to loop through this array and make 3 API calls for each item. And then make an object from these 3 API responses.

```
arrayOfObject.forEach(
      (item) => {
        forkJoin({
          resOne: this.getApiCallOne(item.id),
          resTwo: this.getApiCallTwo(item.id),
          resThree: this.getApiCallThree(item.id),
        }).subscribe(({resOne, resTwo, resThree}) => {
          this.requests.push({
            fullName: resOne.name,
            mobilePhone: resTwo.mobile,
            address: resThree.address
          });
        });
      }
    );
```

I tried this way. Is this a good approach?

Comment: Does the title summarizes the whole question?

Comment: Is the array of ojeccts fixed. cause now you are making 3 forkJoins

Comment: The array of objects will come from an API call

Comment: Don't see any problem with this statement, only thing I can see is, it has multiple subscription. I've prepared single subscription based approach, check [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ls7h8h?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts) here

Answer (score 1):

In terms of hitting api you might want to rethink what you are doing. So based on my understanding you pull data with an api that will receive a array of object, each array you want to pull another 3 api requests. so 1+n*3 requests.

But to answer you question and ignoring the amount of api requests you could do something like this.

```
requestAll(){

 firestApiRequest().pipe(
    mergeMap(res=>{
    return forkJoin(  res.map(item=> this.requestDataFromId(item.id)))
    }).subscribe(results=>{
      this.requests = results;
  }
}
private requestDataFromId(id){
  return forkJoin({
          resOne: this.getApiCallOne(item.id),
          resTwo: this.getApiCallTwo(item.id),
          resThree: this.getApiCallThree(item.id),
        }).pipe(
           map(({resOne, resTwo, resThree}) => {
            fullName: resOne.name,
            mobilePhone: resTwo.mobile,
            address: resThree.address
          }))
    }
}
```